# URL(string:) returns nil for a path that contains cyrillic

Tags: ios, foundation

[NS]URL(string:) returns nil for a path that contains cyrillic

[https://somedomain.ru/upload/files/Оферта.pdf](https://somedomain.ru/upload/files/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0.pdf)

safari in 10.15 opens that url just fine.
Is there a workaround that?

I do it like so:

```
public extension URL {
    static func open(urlString: String) {
        guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
    }
}
```

and never reach UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
(or UIApplication.shared.open(url) if I do URL instead of NSURL
I suppose the two are bridged)

UPD the resolution thanks to Daniel Storm:

static let оферта = "https://somesiteofours.ru/upload/files/" + ("Оферта.pdf".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed) ?? "404")

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to URL encode the path:

```
https://somedomain.ru/upload/files/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0.pdf
```

Apple docs: [addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding)